# Split characters in string to list unless surrounded by multi-digit integers in Python 3

Tags: python, string

If I have the following list:

```
['{', "'", 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', "'", ':', ' ', '3', ',', ' ', "'", 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', "'", ':', ' ', '5', ',', ' ', "'", 'o', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e', 's', "'", ':', ' ', "'", '4', '3', '5', "'", '}']
```

How can I split it such that multi-digit integers are not split? Using the previous example:

```
['{', "'", 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', "'", ':', ' ', '3', ',', ' ', "'", 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', "'", ':', ' ', '5', ',', ' ', "'", 'o', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e', 's', "'", ':', ' ', "'", '435', "'", '}']
```

Comment: what is the starting point of this? the title says you want to "split" stuff - but in the description it seems like you want to "join" things... was this `json` to start with? why not parse the json file?

Comment: When you have consecutive digits, `join` them into a single string.  See your local string tutorial for method (function) names and usage details.

Comment: that seems like a badly read json to str in python, `"{'banana': ", '3', ", 'apple': ", '5', ", 'oranges': '", '435', "'}"`

Comment: Here's a crpytic one-liner: `[s for is_digit, group in itertools.groupby(data, str.isdigit) for s in ([''.join(group)] if is_digit else group)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def func(a):
    st = []
    tmp = ''
    for i in a:
            if i.isdigit():
                    tmp+=i
            else:
                    if tmp!='':
                            st.append(tmp)
                            tmp = ''
                    st.append(i)
    if tmp!='':
            st.append(tmp)
            tmp =''
    return st

a = ['{', "'", 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', "'", ':', ' ', '3', ',', ' ', "'", 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', "'", ':', ' ', '5', ',', ' ', "'", 'o', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e', 's', "'", ':', ' ', "'", '4', '3', '5', "'", '}']
print(func(a))
```

output

```
['{', "'", 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', "'", ':', ' ', '3', ',', ' ', "'", 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', "'", ':', ' ', '5', ',', ' ', "'", 'o', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e', 's', "'", ':', ' ', "'", '435', "'", '}']
```